# x === 0 or x < 1 in Javascript, which is better? And is x < 1 include type checking?

Tags: javascript

Some said that it is recommended to compare with 0.
But in the javascript case `x === 0` is including type checking which is usually slower than `x < 1`.

But that's not a big performance problem. I am just curious about the performance of two operations. In my opinion `x < 1` is better.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: I am just curious about the operations. This is not the optimization case :)

Comment: If you are interested in performance, check [this](https://jsperf.com/triple-equal-vs-less-than)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small comparison that I have made, according to EMCA Standard
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

In the following parts:

- 7.2.12 Abstract Relational Comparison
- 7.2.14 Strict Equality Comparison

---

For **<**, it will call `ToPrimitive` twice, which will also call `Type` twice, then it will call `ToNumber` which have to convert the primitive to Number, therefore there are quite a few type casting happening there that increase the CPU cycle.

However, for **===**, there is a short-circuit that will perform faster if left side is number, thus resulting in lesser CPU cycle.

One example that can illustrate is the following:

```
console.log(1 < "2"); // This return true because "2" is converted to Number
console.log(1 === "1"); // This will return false immediately because it failed Type checking
```

---

Therefore, I will say that **===** should be slightly faster than **<** in terms of CPU cycle

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not sure if this *short-circuit that will perform faster if left side is number* is true. Check https://jsperf.com/triple-equal-vs-less-than

Answer (score 2):

> Some said that it is recommended to compare with 0. But in the javascript case x === 0 is including type checking which is usually slower than x < 1.

**But** they are not equivalent.

`x === 0` compares whether the number is equal to zero. That's it.

`x < 1` on the other hand allows for zero, all negative numbers **and** all numbers between one and zero.

So, I don't see why you must compare the two of them. Just pick the one that best represents the condition you are validating.

> And is x < 1 include type checking?

No. You can easily check that in a browser console.

```js
console.log("0 < 1: " + (0 < 1));
console.log("'0' < 1: " + ('0' < 1));
console.log("0.5 < 1: " + (0.5 < 1));
console.log("'0.5' < 1: " + ('0.5' < 1));
console.log("20 < 1: " + (20 < 1));
console.log("'20' < 1: " + ('20' < 1));
```

Comment: When checking if an array is empty, there are two way to do that.
1. a.length === 0 (don't use == cause the linter complains that)
2. a.length < 1.

Comment: I'd use `=== 0` in that case - whether or not it has minor performance advantage.